# itext7 barcode 39 bar width in Mils

Tags: itext7

Have a new project that requires shipping labels for Amazon shipments.
Amazon sets a requirement that:
5.2.5 Pallet labels must be printed in black ink on a white background **and barcodes must be 20 mils** and support high-speed scanning.

I'm using itext7 (first time user) and VB.net VB and don't have any issues but I'm uncertain if the barcode bar widths meet Amazon's requirements. It's my understanding that .058 is equal to 20 mils barcode width. Itext7 has a "Setsize()" method that controls the X dimension of the Barcode.

Dim PurchaseOrder = New Paragraph

Dim BCODE As iText.Barcodes.Barcode39 = New iText.Barcodes.Barcode39(Pdf)

BCODE.SetCode("3ONWGE7C")

BCODE.SetStartStopText(False)

BCODE.FitWidth(130)

BCODE.SetSize(0.51)

Dim Barcodeimg = New Image(BCODE.CreateFormXObject(Pdf))

PurchaseOrder.Add(Barcodeimg)

The bar code comes out fine when I print and scan it.
Can anyone tell me if I'm going in the right direction. I work solo so an extra set of eyes would really help. I really would like to prevent a bunch of issues with Amazon shipments.

Thanks